# How to renew Azure B2C Sign-in URL SSL certificate?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We've configured Azure B2C SAML application that works fine.
By looking into the B2C Sign-in URL HTTPS SSL certificate validity it shows valid from 15/02/2022 to 15/02/2023. We are sure that we've not taken any additional steps to configure this SSL certificate. URL ex: https://xyz.b2clogin.com/xyz.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_signin/generic/login?EntityId=abc.com

Questions:

1. Is this SSL certificate managed by Azure?
2. Do we need to take any steps when it closes to the expiry date?
   Pls Note: We're using an office 365 free-tier tenant, not using any premium P1 and P2 licenses.

I could not find any MS documentation on how this SSL certificate is being applied whether it's EV OR wildcard certificate. Could you pls share any such documentation link? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As checked with MS support tea, SSL certificates are managed and auto-renewed by MS Azure. No action is required from the customer's perspective to renew this, they also mentioned there is no document/MS guideline page related to this. Thanks.